# JasperReports: Repeating subreport for each value of the list parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I need to develop a report in *JasperReports* which contains **ONE sub-report but the sub-report is repeated for every value** in the list parameter.for example :

Parameter List to be passed to **ONE subreport** : 1,2,3,4

MyReport :

- Subreport(Crosstable+ page break) for value 1 of the passed parameter
- Subreport(Crosstable+ page break) for value 2 of the passed parameter
- Subreport(Crosstable+ page break) for value 3 of the passed parameter
- Subreport(Crosstable+ page break) for value 4 of the passed parameter**

Then the Subreport will also contain another "sub-Subreport" that should be repated X time for each value, example :
Subreport(Crosstable+ page break) for value 1 of the passed parameter :

- "sub-subreport"(another Crosstable) for value 1.1
- "sub-subreport"(another Crosstable) for value 1.2
- "sub-subreport"(another Crosstable) for value 1.3

In other words i'm trying to loop on the same subreport but with different data something like :

```
for(i=0; i<list.lenght();i++){
   print(subreport(i));
}
```

I don't to know how it can be done. I hope my examples are clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your detail band will fire for each record. So, if your input control is $P{myCustomers} and your main report's query is:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers
WHERE $X{IN, customer_id, myCustomers}
```

Then your main report will have one field, $F{customer_id}. Your subreport needs to have a parameter of its own and it will get a value from the main report. Insert your subreport into the detail band of the main report. Click on the subreport from within the main report, and then in the Properties window of the main report, click on Parameters. The "Name" column is the name of the parameter in the subreport that will accept the incoming value, and the "Expression" field is the value to pass. So if your subreport also has a parameter for customer id, the name is customer_id and the expression to pass is $F{customer_id}.

The iReport documentation (http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/ireport-ultimate-guide) has information about subreports on page 90.

Comment: thanks for the solution but actually the problem is the report is more complicated than i have explained, because i don't have one parameter, i have for example 3 parameters : Date_start,Date_end,listOfChoices.  The subreport should execute the query and repeate it self for the number of value of listOfchoices not the number of records for each execution.

Comment: So if listOfChoices = 3, the report runs 3 times for the same date_start to date_end period?

Comment: no the report doesn't run 3 time, it only runs one time... i don't think it's possible to do it using Jaspererport :(  do you think Scriptlet can help ?

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired output? I think it is still a little difficult to tell what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you looking to pass a list of parameters? So you would pass [red, blue, green] and the report would run one time for red, once for blue, and once for green?

Answer (score 0):

Try using report groups: the group is based on a value or on expression then you can embed subreport into the group.